# Why is my loss function returning nan?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient-descent

So I define this custom loss function in Keras using a Tensorflow backend to minimize a background extraction autoencoder. It's supposed to ensure that the prediction x_hat doesn't stray to far from the median of the predictions taken over the batch B0.

```
def ben_loss(x, x_hat):

    B0 = tf_median(tf.transpose(x_hat))
    sigma = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(tf.abs(x_hat - B0) / 0.4), axis=0)
    # I divide by sigma in the next step. So I add a small float32 to sigma
    # so as to prevent background_term from becoming a nan.
    sigma += 1e-22 
    background_term = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(x_hat - B0) / sigma, axis=-1)
    bce = binary_crossentropy(x, x_hat)
    loss = bce + background_term

    return loss
```

When I try the minimize the network using this loss function the loss almost immediately becomes a NaN. Does anyone know why this happening? You can reproduce the error by cloning my repo and running this [script](https://gitlab.com/mdornfe1/dolphin_tagger/blob/master/background_stackoverflow.py).

Comment: Maybe your `x_hat` contains either 0 or a 1. Then `log(0)` or `log(1-1)`  both can become `NaN`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Thanks! I should have specified. I actually checked and the nan is coming from background_term not bce.

Comment: Ok. Then I think it is becoming `NaN` after some small number of mini-batches. Do the following. First reduce `1e-22` to a larger value for now, such as `1e-5`. Then use `train_on_batch()`. My guess is if `NaN` is indeed coming from `background_term` then first few batches loss will not be `NaN`. I think your loss is exponentially increasing and ultimately it becomes NaN. However, this happens too fast to observe in a `fit` function. If this is the case, then just reduce your learning rate or use `adam` or `rmsprop` to start with.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Thanks again. It was actually coming from the derivative of sigma. tf.sqrt(tf.abs(x_hat - B0) was becoming the 0 tensor, which was making its derivative a NaN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was coming from the fact that tf.abs(x_hat - B0) was approaching a tensor with all zeros for entries. This was making the derivative of sigma wrt x_hat a NaN. The solution was to add a small value to that quantity.

```
def ben_loss(x, x_hat):

    B0 = tf_median(tf.transpose(x_hat))
    F0 = tf.abs(x_hat - B0) + 1e-10
    sigma = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt( / 0.4), axis=0)
    background_term = tf.reduce_mean(F0 / sigma, axis=-1)
    bce = binary_crossentropy(x, x_hat)
    loss = bce + background_term

    return loss
```